# Consuming the MS Web CRM API in 3 party Application

Tags: dynamic, crm

I have created an website wherein I'm trying to call the MS Web CRM as below

```
$(function () {

        var ODataURL = "https://***.crm5.dynamics.com/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/Core_territorytypeSet";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: ODataURL,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                //
                // Handle result from successful execution
                //
                // e.g. data.d.results
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorObject) {
                //
                // Handle result from unsuccessful execution
                //
                alert("OData Execution Error Occurred");
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm getting 'unauthorized' error. 
How can we authorize the user before making call to the Api in javascript??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to register your application with Azure Active Directory. Then use the client id to retrieve a token that need to be passed with your web API calls. You can find a good walkthrough here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595797.aspx